# Segmentation fault when switching from Chrome to Chromium with Selenium/Python/Linux

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I have a working Python app using Selenium (headless) and Chrome as the underlying browser. When switching to Chromium I get segmentation faults (error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.25). The app continuous to work though. I am not sure how to get rid of these segmentation faults.

Setup:

- Oracle Linux 8 (compatible with RHEL8/CENTOS8)
- Python 3.9.13
- Selenium 4.8.3
- Chromium 111.0.5563.146
- Chromedriver 111.0.5563.146

This is the code (edited):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import visibility_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from datetime import datetime
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time

chromium_path = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'


options = Options()
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument("--nogpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'

ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random

ser = Service(r"/usr/bin/chromedriver")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=options)
# First Segfault
browser.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
browser.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": userAgent})
# Second Segfault
```

Segmentation fault example:

```
[1282594.979885] chromium-browse[1222575]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f1f96690e38 sp 00007ffc29825c80 error 4 in libstdc++.so.6.0.25[7f1f965fc000+186000]
```

Not sure how to resolve this. Feedback highly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I can reproduce this on a Raspberry Pi Zero, while it runs on a Pi 3. Could it be a single core issue?